# Um arquivo .bat que muda a cor de fundo de acordo com o número que o usuário digitou

Tags: batch, cmd, cores, prompt

O código abaixo deve mudar a cor de fundo depois que o usuário digita um número de 0 a 7, mas o programa fecha logo após o usuário digitar o número e não altera a cor. Estou usando o cmd do win7.

```
 @ECHO OFF
 SET /p num=Digite um numero de zero a sete:

IF %num% == 0 (
color 0f
) ELSE (
IF %num% == 1 (
color 1f
) ELSE (
IF %num% == 2 (
color 2f
) ELSE (
IF %num% == 3 (
color 3f
) ELSE (
IF %num% == 4 (
color 4f
) ELSE (
IF %num% == 5 (
color 5f
) ELSE (
IF %num% == 6 (
color 6f
) ELSE (
IF %num% == 7 (
color 7f
) ELSE (
ECHO error.
)
)
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use esse código:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /p num=Digite um numero de zero a sete:
IF %num% LEQ 7 (
    color %num%f
) ELSE (
    ECHO error.
)

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Arquivos BAT não lidam muito bem com parênteses, a instrução que o IF execute vem do lado dele:
IF [condição] [instrução]
e não:
IF [condição]
    [instrução]

logo:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /p num=Digite um numero de zero a sete:

IF %num% == 0 color 0f
IF %num% == 1 color 1f
IF %num% == 2 color 2f
IF %num% == 3 color 3f
IF %num% == 4 color 4f
IF %num% == 5 color 5f
IF %num% == 6 color 6f
IF %num% == 7 color 7f
pause
```